# HTML file script and CSS placement

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, browser

I was watching [Doug Crockford's Theory of DOM](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y2Y0U-2qJMs) video and at 16:50, he talks about placement of `<script>` tags and CSS `<link>`. He mentions placing `<script src>` as close to bottom of body as possible, and `<link>` as high in the head as possible. From this, I have a few questions:

1) I learned JavaScript by tutorials. Many programs put their JavaScript within their `<head>` tags just after the CSS `<style>` tags. Is the information in his (2006?) video outdated now?

2) Do these rules apply to JavaScript `<script type="text/javascript">` and CSS `<style>` tags as well. If so, why, and what are the differences between these tags and the `<script src>` and `<link>` tags?

3) He says "reduce the number of script files as much as possible"... but if I'm coding a large project, I want to stay away from clumping all my JavaScript together... rather I'd prefer to separate my code out into files that make sense. How much of an impact does this have?

He mentions placement can impact performance, as "the way in which the browser does incremental loading is very sensitive to the placement of these assets." Yet, although I haven't done rigorous performance tests, I haven't noticed large changes in performance from placement differences. He doesn't explain further how this impacts performance and why it's so important.

Comment: A good site which answers most of your questions could be: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/

Comment: @Snowman Okay I've removed that post

Answer (score 1):

1) No, the information is not necessarily outdated, but many people just load all of their resources at once. It is often advised to load scripts at the end of your `<body>` because browsers stop to load the referenced files, lengthening the load time. Style-sheets are included at the beginning of the file so that elements are styled as the document loads, rather than all at once at the end.

2) The `<script src>` and `<link>` tags require a new connection to be opened, slowing load times. The `<script type>` and `<style>` tags are inline, so new connections are not required to be opened and waited on.

3) Each script file is another connection that must be opened. The fewer connections to be opened, the faster the site will load.

Overall, these rules are more effective for reducing load time on slower connections or larger projects.

Answer (score -1):

1) when you are working on large project then if js code and css are used in many pages then you do not put these all code in each and every pages just include the files in your pages.

2) if your code will minify then it will help to load fast.

3) you can use <link> for including css and <script> for javascript.